# Кроссбраузерность. Какие версии браузеров выбрать?

Tags: кроссбраузерность

Новичок.
Существуют огромное количество различных браузеров и их версий. Например, только у IE более 5 версий (IE 6/7/8/9/10/11), не принимая во внимание маленькие доработки. Как мне определиться под какие версии браузеров клепать сайт, и следовательно, на каких версиях тестировать?
(русс.анг)
Спасибо.

Comment: Какие браузеры использует ваша аудитория, под те и клепайте.

Comment: ie 5-10 можно забыть ...

Comment: @MaximLensky забыть проблематично, я знаю как минимум два банка, сайты которых работают только в режиме IE5 и даже в режиме IE7 уже не работают...

Comment: @andreymal а что держит их на ie5 ?

Comment: @MaximLensky я у них не спрашивал, но подозреваю, что «работает - не трогай» )

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, а тебе от меня легенду: https://youtu.be/qpLSN-D05Z8